# Running python files in javascript (possibly using REST API)

Tags: python

I would like to be able to run python code in my javascript. How do I do this?

This is my attempt, but it's not working and I don't know why
The two following files, I have in the same directory if that matters?

Please help, thanks

scripts.js:

```
function postPyScript(input){
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/app.py",
    data: { mydata: input }
});
return jqXHR.responseText;
}


$('#generateBtn').click(function(){
datatosend = 'this is my matrix';
result = postPyScript(datatosend);
alert('Got back ' + result);
});
```

app.py:

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/app.py", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def someFunction():
    message = None
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        datafromjs = request.form['mydata']
        result = "something to return"
        resp = make_response('{"response": '+result+'}')
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
        return respreturn
        return render_template('index.html',message='')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem, but you should maybe change `"/app.py"` to `"/app"`. I'm not sure if flask accepts api endpoints like `"/app.py"`

Comment: there are two returns in `someFunction` - you might want to edit your question for clarity

Comment: [Python interpreter in JS using Skulpt](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40127/34718) (here seen as a Stack snippet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only have one route in flask, it seems that you are likely already using a server to serve your html and javascript - maybe you are using the apache instance that your computer came with? In addition to that, you need to be running your flask server. Your flask server will be running on a different port from your apache (or whatever) server.
So, two things:

- run your flask server. you might do something like:
  `$ cd directory-of-this-project
  $ export FLASK_APP=app.py
  $ flask run`
- change the ajax url to include the port of the flask server (e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:5000/app.py`)